# React Link to same component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Information on this is a little sparse, outdated or just downright convoluted.

Is there no easy way to tell a react `<Link>` or `<NavLink>` element that it's staying on the same page but needs to reload the component it points to?

I understand how to make simple changes to properties, which leads to the page being re-rendered.

The problem is, the links I'm dealing with are part of a Navbar component, so they're separate from the component they need to really act on. Code snippet below:

```
<li>
    <NavLink to={'/page/1'} >
       Page 1
    </NavLink>
</li>
<li>
    <NavLink to={'/page/2'} >
       Page 2
    </NavLink>
</li>
<li>
    <NavLink to={'/page/3'} >
        Page 3
    </NavLink>
</li>
```

In routes.tsx I have:

```
<Route path='/page/:id' component={Page} />
```

This works for the first click of one of the links, but any later attempts are ineffectual. I understand why it's not working, but don't really understand how to fix it.

Surely it's not that hard to tell the page it needs to re-render a specific component?

I found one suggestion telling me to try this in the routes file:

```
<Route exact path='/page/:id' component={(props) => <Page {...props} /> }/>
```

This doesn't show any errors in Visual Studio, but testing the website gives me this:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/routes.tsx:18:101 
TS2322: Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ViewPortfolioProject> & Readonly<{ children?: Reac...'.
Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<RouteComponentProps<{}>>'.
Property 'match' is missing in type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

And that's as far as I can get.

Originally I was using standard `<a href="/page/1">` tags, which worked but caused a full refresh of the entire website before going where I wanted, which isn't really a very 'React' way to do it.

All input appreciated, thanks.

Comment: In your Page component, try shouldComponentUpdate() {return true}

Comment: Does your Page component really sit immediately below the Route, or is there something in between like a redux connect() HOC?

Comment: @jamesemanon where should I write that? And is there any more I should know, or extra bits I need to add? I get errors with everything I try. I'm looking at the info on this page: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Comment: try here, basically, we are forcing a rerender. this should work unless react-router is not rerendering on its own. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: @jamesemanon No luck, I'm afraid. The problem is that the component is already loaded, and it needs to have new properties passed into it. I know how this normally happens within a single component, but I don't know how to send new properties from one component to the other. The Navlink is in a Navbar component which needs to send a new page ID property to the Page component, after which it can re-render. The way things are at the moment, the only thing that seems to change is the URL in the browser address bar. No properties are sent through, otherwise it would surely re-render.

Comment: Could you please provide us the code for your `Page` and `Routes` components to have a further look? if `<Route exact path='/page/:id' component={(props) => <Page {...props} /> }/>` doesn't work (which it should), you can create a custom Route component (CustomRoute for example) where you can pass all the props you need and render conditionally depending on the props.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a key to the component, updating state or calling forceUpdate() with a new key trigger a re-render.